# Chat message notification in PHP and Javascript display only one message instead of multiple

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

im working on notification for new messages from chat system on all pages and it's working but the problem is this, if they are multiple new messages it show me only one notification from user 1 instead of multiple users, user1 user2,and so on..

Here is what i have tried.

PHP Code:

```
if($_POST['action'] == 'show_notification') {

$for= $user->filter->id;

$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM chat WHERE reciever_userid = '$for' AND status = 0 ORDER BY chatid DESC");

$row = $db->fetch($sql);

    $from  = $row['sender_userid'];
    $name  = $user->numePrenume($from);
    $photo  = $user->photoUser($from);
    $message = htmlspecialchars($row['message']);


  $json_data = array(
        "name"  => $name,
        "photo" => $photo,
        "messsage" => $message
    );

echo json_encode($json_data);

}
```

Javascript:

```
setInterval(function(){
 notification();
 }, 6000);
function notification(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"pagini/chat/notificari.php",
        method:"POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data:{action:'show_notification'},
        success:function(response){     
            var name = response.name;
            var messsage  = response.message;
            var photo   = response.photo;
            var sound = new Audio('inc/audio/notificare.mp3');
            var notification = new NotificationFx({
            message : '<div class="ns-thumb"><img width="64" src="'+photo+'"/></div><div class="ns-content"><p><a href="#">'+name+'</a> '+message+'</p></div>',
            layout : 'default',
            ttl : 4000,
            effect : 'thumbslider',
            type : 'notice', // notice, warning, error or success
            onClose : function() {

            }
                        });
            sound.play();
            notification.show();

        }
    });

};
```

Comment: many things wrong, but the reason you only getting one row is your using fetch, and not setting status = 0 to something else.

Comment: Can u help me? I'm beginner with this